# Calculating Stream Order Classification for NHD High Resolution vector data

Tags: qgis, strahler

So I am trying to calculate stream order using the Strahler method. I have vector data from NHD in high resolution and was wondering if anyone has ideas on how to assign stream order using vector data. I prefer opensource solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try the [Strahler plugin](https://github.com/ArMoraer/QGISStrahler), but you'll have to manually select each "root" segment in order to compute the Strahler order.

Answer (score 2):

[NHDplus](https://www.fws.gov/r5gomp/gom/bd/NEAHCP/nhd_plus_metadata.htm) has stream ordering built-in.  However, it is only available for the contiguous lower 48 states.  I recently finished a Strahler ordering project for a large part of Alaska.  Since NHDplus data was not available for my project area, I used the ArcMap [RivEX tool](http://www.rivex.co.uk/) to generate Strahler ordering using the traditional NHD data. The results were splendid.

Answer (score 0):

An answer using Whitebox Tools if stream network doesn't have a plus version:
[Strahler ordering of existing vector stream network data with a DEM (SRTM)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/474781/strahler-ordering-of-existing-vector-stream-network-data-with-a-dem-srtm/474889#474889)