# Strahler ordering of existing vector stream network data with a DEM (SRTM)

Tags: qgis, hydrology

I have a vector stream network (CanVec) and an SRTM DEM.  How can I elucidate the Strahler order and attach that value to the vector stream network?  For some reason the CanVec data doesn't have Strahler order values.  I am using this dataset because Saskatchewan doesn't have a stream network (or one that I am aware of like BC or AB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elucidate the Strahler order (or others) from an existing vector linestring, I utilized [WhiteboxTools](https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/) and an SRTM.  Install WhiteboxTools (donate $) as directed.  I isolated the streams for Strahler Ordering by sub_sub watershed(s) then ran RepairStreamVectorTopology on the isolated stream network before actual analysis.  After repair, I ran VectorStreamNetworkAnalysis on the repaired stream network output / SRTM pair.  The results look good, so far.  I can't believe how quick the analysis took.

[image: subs_sub_watersheds]

[image]